# Angular2. Преобразование xml в json с помощью x2js

Tags: xml, angular2, парсер

У меня есть XML файл, данные из которого я пытаюсь выгрузить - сначала просто текстом, а затем объектом JSON с помощью x2js

```
clickHandler() {
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

   let text = '';
   this.http.get('./xml/text')
        .map((res: Response) => res.text())
        .subscribe(data => text = data);

    const x2js = new X2JS();
    const jsonObj = x2js.xml2js(xml);
    let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    let xml = text; //?? 

   parseString(xml, function (err: any, result: any) {
       alert(result); 
     }
   }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выполнить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно описанию [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js) преобразование в json выполняется функцией `xml2json`.
Но так как Вы получаете данные аяксом, то, соответственно, данное преобразование должно быть выполнено тогда, когда вы получите данные. То есть внутри **subscribe**

```
let text = '';
 this.http.get('./xml/text')
  .map((res: Response) => res.text())
  .subscribe(data => {

     const x2js = new X2JS();
     this.jsonObj = x2js.xml2json(data);
  });
```

Вот так приблизительно это должно выглядеть.